# Generate Imagemagick command for following image (Gradient)

Tags: imagemagick

Can anyone please help me to generate command for following image?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2vZnIXu1nOweDI1aEJRYTYtSWM/view?pli=1

The command which i tried is as follows.

```
convert -size 5256.00x2799.00 xc:transparent -gravity Center -font MyriadProRegular.otf ^
-pointsize "83.00" -interword-spacing 30 -stroke none ( ( -size 1x29 xc:"#A89AD7-#9E87BD" ) ( -size 1x30 gradient:"#A581B1-#B16D92" ) ( -size 1x30 gradient:"#C57195-#D47396" ) -append -scale 89x89! -write mpr:grad ) -fill mpr:grad ^
-annotate +1238.00-1092.00 "[Child 5], &" ^ -delete 1 ^
final_result.png
```

Exact issue i am facing is to get gradient effect in font.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what your exact difficulty is, but maybe this wil help you get there in simple steps, each of which can be debugged and improved individually...

First generate your text:

```
convert -font MyriadPro -pointsize 83 -background none label:"[Child 5], &" text.png
```

Now generate your blurred gradient:

```
convert -size 376x29 \
   gradient:"#A89AD7-#9E87BD" \
   gradient:"#A581B1-#B16D92" \
   gradient:"#C57195-#D47396" \
   -append -blur 0x10 gradient.png
```

[image]

Now overlay:

```
convert gradient.png text.png -compose copy-opacity -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate this helped me .. i will try this with Original big image.

Answer (score 1):

The blended curve your attempting is closer to [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) than a stacked series of gradients.

Try using [-spare-color](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#sparse-color), examples [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#sparse-color), and experiment with blending each color-stop.

```
convert -size 100x100 xc: -sparse-color Inverse \
        '0,0 #A89AD7 0,15 #9E87BD 0,33 #A581B1 0,66 #B16D92 0,85 #C57195 0,99 #D47396' \
        preview.png
```

[image: preview]

```
convert -size 400x100 xc: \( \
             -size 1x100 xc: -sparse-color Inverse \
             '0,0 #A89AD7 0,15 #9E87BD 0,33 #A581B1 0,66 #B16D92 0,85 #C57195 0,99 #D47396' \
             -write mpr:grad +delete
        \) \
        -pointsize 63 -interword-spacing 30 \
        -stroke none -fill mpr:grad \
        -gravity Center -annotate 0 "[Child 5], &" \
        final_result.png
```

[image: final result]

Comment: Thanks for your help.. i learned something new from your code. but somehow gradient effect is not too much visible .. but still i will try with original image.